# detecting whether some records are excluded from an INSERT INTO operation

Tags: sql, ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have a composite primary key on 2 columns in the table I am INSERTing into. I come from working with SQL Server, and I know that if I attempted to insert a duplicate key value into a PK table, it would throw an error.

My problem is, my code is not throwing this kind of error. Can you look at it and see if it's a problem with the code? Or does Access not throw errors for this kind of violation?

[Edit]

I guess I'm looking for a way to just acknowledge that duplicate records are attempted to be inserted. I want the current functionality to remain (dups are tossed; valid records are inserted). I don't want the entire INSERT to get rolled back.

My code is below.

```vbs
Function InsertData(Ignore As String)  

    ' define file path of CSV to be imported
    Dim CurrentDate As String
    Dim CurrentYear As String

    CurrentDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    CurrentYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")


    Dim Exfile As String
    Exfile = iPath + "\" + CurrentYear + "\" + "FileName" + CurrentDate + ".txt"

    'this calls a saved import routine
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "tbl_TEMP"


    'merge data with that already existing in tbl_Perm.
    'the clustered PK on product_ID and As_of_Date prevents dup insertion
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim errLoop As Error

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase(iPath + "\ExDatabase.mdb")
        dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Perm (Col1,Col2,Date_Created) " _
                    & "SELECT ColA + ColB, ColC, Format$(Now(),'Short Date')" _
                    & "FROM tbl_TEMP;"

        ' Trap for errors, checking the Errors collection if necessary.
        On Error GoTo Err_Execute

        'delete temp table
        dbs.Execute "DROP TABLE tbl_TEMP;"

    dbs.Close

Err_Execute:
    ' Notify user of any errors that result from
    ' executing the query.
    If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 0 Then
    For Each errLoop In DBEngine.Errors
    MsgBox "Error number: " & errLoop.Number & vbCr & _
    errLoop.Description
    Next errLoop
    End If
 Resume Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the INSERT to proceed and determine whether any duplicates were rejected then you could do something like this

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlSelect As String, sourceRecords As Long
Set cdb = CurrentDb
sqlSelect = _
        "SELECT ColA + ColB, ColC, Format$(Now(),'Short Date') " & _
        "FROM tbl_TEMP"
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM (" & sqlSelect & ")", dbOpenSnapshot)
sourceRecords = rst!n
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "INSERT INTO tbl_Perm (Col1,Col2,Date_Created) " & sqlSelect)
qdf.Execute
If qdf.RecordsAffected < sourceRecords Then
    Debug.Print sourceRecords - qdf.RecordsAffected & " record(s) not inserted"
End If
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Comment: wow - this is great. i will attempt to implement as soon as i get exclusive control of the DB :(

Answer (score 2):

From the Microsoft DAO Doc ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx)):

> In a Microsoft Access workspace, if you provide a syntactically
>   correct SQL statement and have the appropriate permissions, the
>   Execute method won't fail — even if not a single row can be modified
>   or deleted. Therefore, always use the dbFailOnError option when using
>   the Execute method to run an update or delete query. This option
>   generates a run-time error and rolls back all successful changes if
>   any of the records affected are locked and can't be updated or
>   deleted.

So add the `dbFailOnError` option to your call.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my description. I guess I'm looking for a way to just acknowledge that duplicate records are attempted to be inserted. I want the current functionality to remain (dups are tossed; valid records are inserted). I don't want the entire `INSERT` to get rolled back.

Comment: Then I'd suggest using the `RcordsAffected` property to see if the number of rows inserted is equal to the number of rows expected from the Select.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
```

is after you execute your SQL statement. The **Err_Execute** block will - in this case - be called every time because there is not statement like `Exit Function` before the label. I am not sure what happens to the errors if you close the connection before evaluating the error collection.

Comment: sorry, i'm not fully understanding you. Where would I put `Exit Function` in my code?

Comment: You have to put the On Error GoTo before the code that can cause the error, and `Exit Function` before the Err_Execute-Block, otherwise it will be executed every time.